# How do I get gvim to start maximised in Windows?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, window-management

I'd like to have my editors give me as much screen real estate as possible since it increases my ability to see most of the code at once.

The problem is that `gvim` seems to give me either an 80x25 window or remember the last non-maximised size, depending on how I invoke it.

So, how can I force it to be as large as possible, irrespective of any remembered state?

Comment: I will in fact recommand the plugin https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell, which works for gvim on win32 and win64 both, with <F11> Toggle between Fullscreen/normal mode

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can put this line:

```
autocmd GUIEnter * simalt ~x
```

at the end of your `gvimrc` file.

This method uses the `autocmd` feature to weave its magic. The command `autocmd GUIEnter *` specifies a command to run after successfully starting the GUI for a file pattern of `*` (any file).

The command it will execute, `simalt ~x` (in Windows variants of `vim` only), will simulate the keystroke <kbd>Alt Spacebar</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, which are the keystrokes that will maximise the window.

You can also use the shortened version:

```
au GUIEnter * sim ~x
```

but I prefer fully expanded commands myself, especially since it's the sort of thing you set and forget, only entering *once* when installing `vim` onto a Windows system.

---

Keep in mind that this is simulating keystrokes in order to achieve its ends. On English versions, it will work fine since <kbd>Alt-Space</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> is how you maximise a window.

If that doesn't work for you, you should investigate the keystrokes in whatever locale you're using. For example, the French version will use `Agrandir` (enlarge) with the `n` as the control keystroke, so the command you would need there is:

```
autocmd GUIEnter * simalt ~n
```

(which would actually *minimise* your window in English).

If you're some *other* (non-English, non-French) variant, just press <kbd>Alt-Space</kbd> on a window to bring up the system menu, and find out what key should be used (it should be underlined).

---

To *find* your `gvimrc` file for adding whatever command you need, you can enter:

```
:version
:echo $VIM
:echo $HOME
```

and you should get a list of startup files and variables like:

```
system gvimrc file = "$VIM/gvimrc"
  user gvimrc file = "$HOME/_gvimrc"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim
C:\Users\Pax\Documents
```

Comment: Your shortened version of the autocmd is missing the `*`.

Comment: This method doesn't work for me: instead of maximizing the window it opens a pop-up menu allowing to restaure, move, minimize, maximize(...) the window. I'm using Windows 7 SP1 and gvim 7.4.711. How can I make it work?

Comment: @statox, that's what you'd see if you left off the `x` from the end. Make sure you have the _full_ text `au GUIEnter * sim ~x`.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm not sure to understand I copied the full line (both long and short version) from `au` to `~x`. Is there a whitespace caracter I'm missing or something like that?

Comment: @statox, when you have a gvim window open and you mouse-click the system button (the vim icon most top-left, above the file menu), do you see a maximize? When that system menu is open, does it maximise when you press x?

Comment: @paxdiablo, I understand the problem now: when I open this menu pressing `x` doesn't maximize the window. On mmy system it is the key `n` which does the job (probably because it is a french system). Thank you for your comment it helped me to understand what happened!

Comment: Good point, @statox, I'll update the answer to mention how it works and how locale can affect it.

Comment: My system is Windows 7. When I open `nvim-qt`, I can hit `Alt-Space-x` and it is maximized. However, adding the line you mentioned in `init.vim` doesn't work. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 11):

In alternative to the maximized window, why do not gain more space for a full vim multiwindows editing experience with an autostart FULL SCREEN mode? ;-)

FULL SCREEN screenshot of the final result (= ALL THE VIDEO pixels capacity):
[image: video full screen screenshot]

In my opinion that's better than a windows maximize: a complete FULL SCREEN (as I used to do with puTTY with ALT-Enter when editing on remote unix terminal...)

I explain how to:

**Step 1**

Install the excellent beautiful utility to allow full screen use in gvim on Windows:

https://github.com/derekmcloughlin/gvimfullscreen_win32/tree/master

You have to download DLL file **gvimfullscreen.dll** and put it in the same directory where gvim.exe is ($VIM/vim74 with gVim release 7.4). To download the DLL (without using git):

https://github.com/derekmcloughlin/gvimfullscreen_win32/raw/master/gvimfullscreen.dll

**Step 2**

Edit **.vimrc** file (inside vim: `:e $HOME/.vimrc`), inserting these commands to autostart full screen and allowing a F11 function key to toggle modes among 3 states: full screen, window maximized, original/default windows size:

```
"run the command immediately when starting vim
autocmd VimEnter * call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)

" activate/deactivate full screen with function key <F11>  
map <F11> <Esc>:call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)<CR>
```

**Step 3**

Edit **.gvimrc** file  (inside vim: `:split $HOME/.gvimrc`) inserting these commands to avoid menu bar and useless stuff:

```
set guioptions-=m  "remove menu bar
set guioptions-=T  "remove toolbar
set guioptions-=r  "remove right-hand scroll bar
set guioptions-=L  "remove left-hand scroll bar
```

Comment: Is there a gvimwin64fullscreen? or can we compile it use the project on github?

Comment: Yeah, I found it here:https://github.com/derekmcloughlin/gvimfullscreen_win32/blob/cef3cc3700501ef36304c5380a69485081c90dfb/gvimfullscreen_64.dll?raw=true

Comment: This `.dll` file used to work for me, but it does not anymore. I suspect that it does not work with gvim 8.0.

Answer (score 3):

From [`:help 'lines'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27lines%27):

> Number of lines of the Vim window.
> [...]
> When Vim is running in the GUI or in a resizable window, setting this
> option will cause the window size to be changed.
> [..]
> You can use this command to get the tallest window possible:
> `:set lines=999`

The `columns` option does the same, except for the width (in characters).

So you could, for example, put this in your vimrc file:

```
set lines=55
set columns=120
```

This is *not* the same as being maximized (even if you use the `999` value as described above), since "being maximized" is a special flag put on the window, and subtly changes some operations (like moving), but it should solve your problem of having a small 80x25 window size by default.

Comment: That's not too bad, though it gives a `234x56` window on my system whereas maximising gives `236x57`. Still, being short two columns and one row at that size is not _too_ much of an issue, especially for something that may work in non-Windows platforms as well, though I haven't actually tested it. I'll have a look tonight when I get home to my beloved Debian box :-)

Comment: With my Debian, the default window is 200x50, setting both lines and columns to 999 in any of `vim` itself, rc file or with `gvim -c 'set them'` gives me 236x61 and maximising gives 237x61, so even closer than under Windows. Interestingly, `gvim -geometry 999x999` gives me a maximised window at the slightly larger size so that may be better for non-Windows though I suspect it'll be harder to ensure all invocation methods use that. Pity there's not a simalt type thing for nonWin platforms.

Comment: Still, it's worth some rep since it comes close enough, and is more portable than the win-only method. By the way, using 9999x9999 as geometry freaks out `vim` since it doesn't like windows with dimensions over 64K pixels (geometry is character cells in this case rather than pixels). 999x999 seems to work okay. Not sure how this would go in a multi-monitor systems.

Comment: Yeah, this method isn't perfect, but like you mentioned, it's cross-platform, and it may also be faster (running commandline-tools on startup can cause a bit of a delay on Windows Vim, at least, that was the case when I used it a few years ago).

Comment: Setting the columns/lines to `160 x 42` gives a window shape approximating the [golden ratio](http://io9.com/5985588/15-uncanny-examples-of-the-golden-ratio-in-nature), and you get the awesomeness of `42` !

Comment: Be aware that `set lines=999` can be buggy. gVim is a little finicky about its interactions with window management constraints (at least on Linux) and might wind up hiding the command line (ie. the status line is the last visible line) until you do something to force it to recalculate its layout, like manually resizing the window. (It's been that way for as long as I've been using Vim and remains a risk in Vim 8.1.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the gVim-specific commands in the other answers, there are a couple standard Windows features to launch any application maximized.

If you are staring gVim from a shortcut, such as from the Start Menu or Desktop, you can change the shortcut properties to start Vim maximized. Right-click the shortcut, choose Properties, and select Maximized from the Run drop-down list. However, this will only affect that shortcut, so gVim will still open in a small window if launched from another shortcut, the Run dialog box, or the command line.

If you are starting gVim from the command line or a batch file, you can use CMD’s `start` command: `start "" /max "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe"`. (The `""` is required if the path to gvim.exe is quoted. If you use an unquoted path without spaces, you can omit it: `start /max C:\Progra~2\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe`.)

Comment: I don't how what the default `start` command is, but I overwrote my PATH and now mingsys's `start` is there, so beware you're running the right one

Comment: I tried this ("from a shortcut ... select Maximized").  The window flashed and then appeared the same size as it had just from starting it from a DOS cmd shell.  To be fair, I have commands in my .vimrc that explicitly set a size (lines/columns) so I suspect the latter is overriding the attempt to maximize.

Comment: This sort of thing also exists as a function of some Linux window managers. For example, I like my Vim windows to be full-height, but two of my monitors are 1024px tall, while the centre one is 1080px tall. Setting Vim to start vertically maximized using KDE's "Window Rules" control panel ensures that gVim will resize to match as it's moved from monitor to monitor. (It also has the added benefit of overriding the `lines` setting, so I can leave that in my `gvimrc` as a fallback for systems where I didn't set up such a tweak.)