# How to resize vim on Windows 7?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

I am wondering how to resize the gVim application on Windows 7. For example, I want to grab the corner of the window with my mouse and resize the application so it takes up more space on my screen. Does anyone know how to do this? This question seems silly, but searching on Google just brings back results on resizing Vim windows and splits, not the Vim program as a whole.

I am using gVim 7.4 on Windows 7. When I start it up it is a very small window, not even 30 lines long.

gVim Easy lets me resize the application, but I don't want to use gVim Easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the 
[`'lines'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#E593) and 
[`'columns'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#E594)
options from within Vim to resize the window. For example:

```
:set lines=55
:set columns=120
```

You can add this to your vimrc file to do it automatically. This will work on gVim on any platform, and in *most* terminal emulators.

Related question: [How do I get gvim to start maximised in Windows?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1937/51)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to drag the corner of the window with your mouse. I can resize gVim on Windows 7 this way. The Vim shortcut opens a console window that cannot be resized larger by dragging it with the mouse, so make sure you're running gVim and not Vim.

Alternatively, you can use the keyboard to resize gVim. The exact key sequence to access the Size system menu item depends on the setting of [`winaltkeys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27winaltkeys%27). If it is set to `yes`, you can use Alt+Space to open the system menu. If set to `menu` or `no`, you will need to press and release Alt, and then press Space. After the menu appears, press S to go into resize mode. Use an arrow key to select which side of the window to resize, and then arrow keys to resize that side. This is standard functionality for all (normal) Windows applications, although the `winaltkeys` setting is particular to gVim.

Another quick keyboard resizing method in Windows 7 is to hold the Windows key and press the left or right arrow keys. This will make gVim half the size of your monitor on either the left or right side of the screen. This is another standard feature in Windows 7.

Finally, if you are running Vim (the console version), you can still resize the application. Click the system menu (the Vim icon in the upper-left corner of the window, just left of the window title, or press Alt+Space to open the menu) and choose Properties. The Layout tab contains two up-down edit boxes for the Window Size, and increasing them will enlarge your Vim window. If you want to make the window smaller, edit the Screen Buffer sizes. (Basically, you probably want both the Screen Buffer and Window Sizes to match for a console Vim window, and editing either one of them in this manner will automatically update the other.) This is also a standard Windows feature for any console window.

Comment: I didn't realize I had both Vim and gVim, you are right that gVim can be resized with the mouse. I thought the whole Windows version I am using was called gVim, now I know.

Answer (score 3):

@Carpetsmoker♦ 's proposal is great enough. But you can also consider to map those command with some key so you can resize your windows just as using your mouse.
For example, write this in your `_vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <C-\> :set columns+=1<CR>
```

so every time you hit `Crtl+\` you will make your larger with one more column(you can also set it to be two or so).

The same,`nnoremap <C-\> :set lines+=1<CR>` give you one more line.

Or you can try any other key-mappings. Anyway, this is really cool~~

Also, if you want to add columns and lines simultaneously, you can do it with this command:

```
nnoremap <C-[> :set columns+=1 <bar> set lines+=1<CR>
```

the `<bar>` stand for `|`, which enable you to achieve multiple commands on the same line when you are in your gvim.

For more, see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249275/vim-multiple-commands-on-same-line/3249303#3249303

and also:[How to map two commands with only one key](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/how-to-map-two-commands-with-only-one-key/3886#3886)