# How to map two commands with only one key

Tags: gvim, vim-windows, window-management

My question comes from this two commands I added on my `_vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <C-[> :set columns+=1<CR>
nnoremap <C-]> :set lines+=1<CR>
```

As is known, it will resize your gvim (I am using gvim on windows) with one more column when you hit <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd>, and one more line when you hit <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd>. That is really cool since you can achieve that resizement as though you are using your mouse.

I wonder if I can map those two command with only one key to make it more comfortable.

Comment: Beware that `<C-[>` is the same as `<ESC>`.  It's a really bad idea to mess with that.  You might want to choose a different key combination.

Comment: @lcd047 oh yeah that is right. thanks for that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with `\|` on unix in the `.vimrc` file, or with `<bar>` on windows in the `_vimrc` file.

e.g.

```
" unix
nnoremap <C-[> :set columns+=1 \| lines+=1<CR> 
" windows
nnoremap <C-[> :set columns+=1 <bar> lines+=1<CR>
```

See the documentation : `:help :bar`

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249303/2558252

Comment: the `|` is good, but that doesn't work in `_vimrc` file. It would be ok if you replace it with `<bar>` (as the answer in stackoverflow suggest)

Comment: Why doesn't `|` work in Windows?

Comment: `|` doesn't work, you either need `\|` or `<bar>`.

Comment: on the documentation, there is no mention of this incompatibility. But as @michaelmichael said on he's answer : `NB: You may find that your ~/.vimrc doesn't support mapping |, or \|. In these cases, try using <bar> instead.`

Comment: This answer is very much incorrect. Even without escaping `\|` for `nnoremap`, it would only work if `columns+=1` was a command, but it's actually a setting. `set lines+=1 columns+=1` would be correct (changing multiple settings from the same `:set` command.

Comment: When using in `<expr>` both mac and windows have to use `<bar><bar>` instead of `||` to express logical or. @filbranden

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend you to use for example `<C-P>`, since `<C-[>` is the same as `<Esc>` and `<C-]>` is used to jump to a definition of the keyword under the cursor.

You can just do this:

```
nnoremap <C-P> <Esc>:set columns+=1 lines+=1<CR>
```

The another way is to use the command separator `|`, but you have to escape it or use `<Bar>` to use it as an argument for the `nnoremap` command, otherwise it would be recognized as command separator in the vimrc file, not in the mapping.

```
nnoremap <C-P> <Esc>:set columns+=1 \| set lines+=1<CR>
```

So when you press `<C-P>`, this command is executed:

```
set columns+=1 | set lines+=1
```

Comment: But also note that the `<C-p>` is used to autocomplete text in vim, which is a built-in utility. I haved used a `<M-p>` instead. But anyway, the`<Esc>` in front of the command is a very good addition.

Comment: @Alex You have mapped it only in normal mode. So you can still use `<C-P>` in insert mode to autocomplete text.

Comment: oh yes you are right.

Answer (score 3):

I was mapping two commands to one F-key to execute 2 plugin commands and none of the above worked for me.
The only option that worked for me was with to `<CR>`:

```
nnoremap <F10> :Doctest <CR> :lwindow<CR>
```

Comment: That's because user-commands such as `:Doctest` typically don't accept `|` as a separator (they take it as an argument.) See `:help :bar` which explains a lot of that. One solution is to use `:execute`: `nnoremap <F10> :execute 'Doctest' \| lwindow<CR>`. But yeah using two separate `<CR>`s would work for sure.

Comment: Thx this helped!